# how to make picture and log in more responsive

Tags: html, css

I need help with making my website more responsive so that the image does not disappear when you scale and that log into adapts the screen size without making it look strange

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7vpv5tec/

Comment: can we see what you have so far? maybe we can find an error or something in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set images width and height in % (percent) instead of using px or em.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people use the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework. It is really easy to implement, and you only need basic knowledge of HTML and CSS to work wonders in terms of resposivness! :)

Comment: ah, this is a comment, in fact, the person who commented on the question first, has a better solution than this, and so he wrote it as a comment.  avoid -1 from users =/

Comment: In a generic question a generic answer is to be expected :)